# Tablas se van recorriendo hacia abajo

Tags: php, html, css

[image: Se mueven las tablas]Me pidieron crear una tabla gigantesca y por algunos motivos (SQL, formato, etc.) tuve que crear una tabla por cada columna y ponerlas juntas para que parezcan una gran tabla, ahora ya llegué a ocupar todo el ancho de la página y mis tablas se pasan a la parte de abajo en lugar de mostrar una barra de desplazamiento en la parte de abajo; ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se sigan mostrando mis tablas juntas? en otro lado leí que una tabla se puede hacer responsiva pero aparece una barra para moverse por la tabla yo quiero poder mover toda la página. De antemano Gracias. 

PD: solo usé `aling= left` en todas las tablas para que me salieran juntas


Soy algo nuevo para programar en **html+php** tengo algo parecido a esto pero repetido muuuchas veces

```
`<table width="50" align="left">
<th colspan="2">Piso</th>
<?php
# connect to a DSN "mydb" with a user and password 
$connect2 = odbc_connect("proyecto", "JP", "0000") or die("Error 
Connect to Database");
$query2 = "SELECT sum (IIF([contactode] = 'PISO',1,0))                 
 FROM datos 
 where vendedor <> 'CASA' and (fecha_reg between #$newDate1# and #$newDate2# 
)  
 GROUP BY datos.vendedor
 ORDER BY datos.vendedor";
 # perform the query2
$result2 = odbc_exec($connect2, $query2);
# fetch the data from the database
$b=0;
while(odbc_fetch_row($result2)){
  $b1 = round ($b1 = odbc_result($result2, 1));
  $piso[$b] = $b1;  
  $b++;  
  $sumatoria_piso += $b1;
}
for($b=0;$b<$zz;$b++){
  $b2 = $piso[$b];   
  @$b4= ($b2 / $sumatoria_piso) *100;  
  $b4 = round($b4,1);  
  $b4 = $b4 . "%";  
  print("<tr><td>$b2</td><td style=color:456789;font-size:82%;>$b4</td>
</tr>");
}
@$porciento_piso = ($sumatoria_piso / $sumatoria_piso) * 100;
$porciento_piso = round ($porciento_piso);
$porciento_piso.= "%";
print("<td> $sumatoria_piso</td><td style=color:456789;font-size:82%;> 
$porciento_piso</td>");
# close the connection

odbc_close($connect2);
$sumatoria = 0;
?>
</table>`
```

Después pediré ayuda para crear una función para las conexiones y usar conexión PDO pero eso es otro tema; perdón por la mala identación pero no me la copió como yo la tengo mi código, lo que está en **header** creo que es CSS 1.0 porque no estoy usando otro archivo si no que está en el mismo, es esto:

```
     <style>
     table, td, th {    
     border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 95%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;    
}

th {
    background-color: #7fbfdf;
    padding: 10px;  
}
td {
    padding: 3px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #e5f2f8}
tr:last-child{background-color: #feff65}
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Como se ve en la imagen me aparecen las tablas en la parte de abajo y aparte interfiere con el **footer** que hice, quiero que sigan apareciendo hacia la derecha

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: hiciste una consulta por cada campo de la tabla, ¿entendí bien?

Comment: Verifica cual es width del contenedor de las tablas, adjunta el código para poder ser mas efectivo.

Comment: Algo por el estilo

Comment: ¿no sería más útil hacer una consulta a varias tablas? Algo así como:
Select Tabla1.Campo,Tabla2.campo
from Tabla1,Tabla2
De esa manera tendrías una sola consulta, y por consecuente, se vería una sola "tabla", en vez de muchas, juntadas para que parezcan una.

Comment: Esa también era mi idea pero no pude hacerlo de esa manera porque la tabla es muy grande y complicada, cada columna tiene sus propios **where** y sus propios **order by** y cada una realiza cálculos con porcentajes y muchas cosas más, me vi forzado a hacerlo así :/

Comment: añade a tu pregunta un ejemplo de las consultas que estás haciendo, y el esquema de la base de datos si es posible, a lo mejor la respuesta está en el modo de hacer la consulta.

Comment: Es un poco complicado,estoy haciendo un proyecto a una empresa, me dieron una base de datos en Access, es una sola tabla con muuchos campos y no quieren que la cambie para nada. Cada consulta es parecida a esta: `"SELECT sum (IIF([venta_auto] = 'NUEVO',1,0))                 
 FROM datos where (fecha_v_auto >= #$newDate1# and fecha_v_auto  <= #$newDate2# and vendedor <> 'CASA')
 and  (fecha_reg >= #$newDate1# and fecha_reg  <= #$newDate2# and vendedor <> 'CASA')
 or  (fecha_reg >= #$newDate1# and fecha_reg  <= #$newDate2# and vendedor <> 'CASA')
 GROUP BY vendedor
 ORDER BY vendedor";`

Comment: Por el momento tengo 20 tablas de las cuales 12 tienen consultas así y las otras 8 tienen cálculos que hago poniendo las consultas en arreglos, hago los cálculos y luego imprimo las tablas, por estas razones tuve que hacerlo así :(

Comment: ya, entiendo. Buscaré algo que ví el otro día, a ver si te sirve.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: esto fue lo que vi el otro día, lo tenía en el historial, no sé si sea de tu ayuda, pero te lo dejo por aquí.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_hor_scroll

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal es tener un div que envuelva  a la tabla y poner `overflow: auto;` para hacer que tenga scroll horizontal. Aquí un ejemplo

```css
div#wrapper{
    overflow: auto;
}
#wrapper table{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#wrapper td{
    border: 1px black solid;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem ipsum
        <table><!-- tabla dentro de otra tabla -->
          <tr>
            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Me puso mis tablas un poco más juntas pero siguen apareciendo hacia abajo las demás :/

Comment: ¿podrías editar tu pregunta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/82241/edit) y añadir un ejemplo reducido de la estructura de tu tabla? para ver cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: ok dame un momento